# In Xcode, what does it mean when an autocompletion suggestion is crossed out?

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

In Xcode 11, what does it mean when an autocompletion suggestion is crossed out?
Like so:

[image: screenshot]

---

In this example, the signature of `onSubmit` is:

```swift
@IBAction private func onSubmit(sender: UIButton)
```

which is matching the list from [*Responding to Button Taps*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton#1656595) in `UIButton`'s documentation.

Comment: Some answers state that this is a bug, others that this normally means that the symbol is deprecated... Btw, can you try to anonymize the first param in the signature and see if it is still happening? ( `onSubmit(_ sender: UIButton)` )

Comment: What do you mean by "the symbol is deprecated"?  It's still on the UIButton doc page.

Comment: I mean the crossed-out symbol, which in your case is not deprecated obviously, hence probably an Xcode bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular example is just a bug in the version of Xcode you're using. Update to Xcode 12 beta and it will go away (code completion is greatly improved there).

For now, you can write `self.ons`... and ask for code completion, and the crossing-out will go away. Or else just select it despite the crossing-out and move on.